# Private variable does not return appropriately

Tags: java

As the title above states - the problem I've encountered is related to the private variable within the class. The private variable does not return the correct value.

My objective is to retrieve private variable named `myIncome` from `income` Class which is a parent to these methods.
But when I try to retrieve myIncome using `objIncome.getIncome();` in another class - it returns `0.00` value.

The result should be based on the if statements output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class income {

    private double income;
    private double myIncome;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");

    public void summery1(double myIncome, double income, double tax, double nic, double personalTAXAllowance, double personalNICAllowance,double taxed, double niced){
        this.myIncome = myIncome;
        System.out.println("Your income before tax: " + income);
        System.out.println("Personal allowance: " + personalTAXAllowance);
        System.out.println("NIC allowance: " + personalNICAllowance);
        System.out.println("Tax rate: " + tax + " %");
        System.out.println("National insurance rate: " + nic + " %");
        System.out.println("Your annual income after tax: " + df.format(myIncome));
        System.out.println("Your income on monthly basis: " + df.format(myIncome / 12) + "\n");
    }
    public void summery2(double myIncome, double income, double tax, double nic, double personalTAXAllowance, double personalNICAllowance,double taxed, double niced, double additionalNIC, double resault){
        this.myIncome = myIncome;
        System.out.println("Your income before tax: " + income);
        System.out.println("Personal allowance: " + personalTAXAllowance);
        System.out.println("NIC allowance: " + personalNICAllowance);
        System.out.println("Tax rate: " + tax + " %");
        System.out.println("National insurance rate: " + nic + " %");
        System.out.println("Your annual income after tax: " + df.format(myIncome));
        System.out.println("Your income on monthly basis: " + df.format(myIncome / 12) + "\n");
    }


    public void clcSalary(){

        System.out.println("Please enter your annual salary before tax");
        double income = input.nextDouble();

        if (income <= 32010){ 

            double tax = 0.20; 
            double nic = 0.12; 
            double personalTAXAllowance = 9440; 
            double personalNICAllowance = 7748; 

            double taxed = (income - personalTAXAllowance) * tax;
            double niced = (income - personalNICAllowance) * nic;

            myIncome = income - (taxed + niced);

            summery1(myIncome, income, tax, nic, personalTAXAllowance,personalNICAllowance,taxed,niced);

        }
        else if (income > 32010 && income < 150000 ){
            double tax = 0.40; 
            double nic = 0.12; 
            double personalTAXAllowance = 9440; 
            double personalNICAllowance = 7748; 

            double taxed = (income - personalTAXAllowance) * tax;
            double niced = (income - personalNICAllowance) * nic;

                if (income > 41444){
                    double additionalNIC = income - 41444;
                    double resault = additionalNIC * 0.02; 
                    this.myIncome = income - (taxed + niced) + resault;
                    summery2(myIncome, income, tax, nic, personalTAXAllowance,personalNICAllowance,taxed,niced,additionalNIC, resault);

                }
                else{
                    this.myIncome = income - (taxed + niced);
                    summery1(myIncome,income, tax, nic, personalTAXAllowance,personalNICAllowance,taxed,niced);
                }
            }
        else{
            double tax = 0.45; 
            double nic = 0.12; 
            double personalTAXAllowance = 9440; 
            double personalNICAllowance = 7748; 

            double taxed = (income - personalTAXAllowance) * tax;
            double niced = (income - personalNICAllowance) * nic;

                if (income > 41444){
                    double additionalNIC = income - 41444;
                    double resault = additionalNIC * 0.02;
                    this.myIncome = income - (taxed + niced) + resault;
                    summery2(myIncome, income, tax, nic, personalTAXAllowance,personalNICAllowance,taxed,niced,additionalNIC, resault);
                }
                    else{
                        this.myIncome = income - (taxed + niced);
                        summery1(myIncome, income, tax, nic, personalTAXAllowance,personalNICAllowance,taxed,niced);
                    }
        }
    }
    public void clcHourlyRate(double income){

        System.out.println("Please enter your hourly rate: \n");
        double hourlyRate = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the hours you've worked this week \n");
        double hoursWeek = input.nextDouble();

        income = ((hourlyRate * hoursWeek) * 4) * 12;

        if (income <= 32010){ 

            double tax = 0.20; 
            double nic = 0.12; 
            double personalTAXAllowance = 9440; 
            double personalNICAllowance = 7748; 

            double taxed = (income - personalTAXAllowance) * tax;
            double niced = (income - personalNICAllowance) * nic;
            this.myIncome = income - (taxed + niced) / 12;
            summery1(myIncome, income, tax, nic, personalTAXAllowance,personalNICAllowance,taxed,niced);
        }
        else if (income > 32010 && income <= 150000 ){

            double tax = 0.40;
            double nic = 0.12; 
            double personalTAXAllowance = 9440; 
            double personalNICAllowance = 7748;

            double taxed = (income - personalTAXAllowance) * tax;
            double niced = (income - personalNICAllowance) * nic;


                if (income > 41444){
                    double additionalNIC = income - 41444;
                    double resault = additionalNIC * 0.02;
                    this.myIncome = ((income - (taxed + niced)) / 12) + resault;
                    summery2(myIncome, income, tax, nic, personalTAXAllowance,personalNICAllowance,taxed,niced,additionalNIC, resault);
                }
                    else{
                        myIncome = (income - (taxed + niced)) / 12;
                        myIncome = income - (taxed + niced) / 12;
                        summery1(myIncome, income, tax, nic, personalTAXAllowance,personalNICAllowance,taxed,niced);
                    }
                }
        else{
            double tax = 0.45; 
            double nic = 0.12; 
            double personalTAXAllowance = 9440; 
            double personalNICAllowance = 7748; 

            double taxed = (income - personalTAXAllowance) * tax;
            double niced = (income - personalNICAllowance) * nic;

                if (income > 41444){

                    double additionalNIC = income - 41444;
                    double resault = additionalNIC * 0.02;
                    this.myIncome = ((income - (taxed + niced)) / 12) + resault;

                    summery2(myIncome, income, tax, nic, personalTAXAllowance,personalNICAllowance,taxed,niced,additionalNIC, resault);
                }
                    else{
                        this.myIncome = (income - (taxed + niced)) / 12;

                        summery1(myIncome, income, tax, nic, personalTAXAllowance,personalNICAllowance,taxed,niced);
                }
            }
        }
    public double getIncome(){
        return myIncome;
        }
    }
```

Here is the entire code of the whole class.

```
public class savings {

    private double v_sav;

    private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private income myincome = new income();

    public void setSavings() {

        double income = myincome.getIncome();

        System.out.println(income);

        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of months: ");
        int months = input.nextInt();

        df.format(v_sav = income * months);
        System.out.println("Your savings in " + months + " months"+ "will be: "+ v_sav);

    }

    public double getSavings() {

        return v_sav;
    }
}
```

This is the class which uses the getIncome method from Class Income object.

```
public class PFA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int option;

        do{
mainMenu();
            option = input.nextInt();
            if (option > 5){
                System.out.println("Please enter a value between 1 and 5");
            }
            else{
                if (option == 1){
                    menuIncome(v_income);
                }
                else if (option == 2){
                    menuExpenses(n_expenses, c_expenses, v_choice, v_exit);
                }
                else if (option == 3){
                    savings mySavings = new savings();

                    mySavings.setSavings();
                    System.out.println(mySavings.getSavings());
                }
            }
        }while (option != 5);
```

Main method.

Comment: What private variable?

Comment: `getIncome()` can never return `null`.

Comment: `double` is a value type, it cannot *possibly* be `null`.

Comment: @Makoto private double myIncome, which is declared in Class Income, which is a parent class for the methods specified above.

Comment: What are you expecting it to return? Don't assume java is doing it wrong.

Comment: Since the question concerns that private variable, it'd be nice if you posted the entire class and getter.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I do not assume, I know the return I get from this getter is wrong.

Comment: @Makoto I've edited my original post. The entire code for that particular class is now available.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis with all respect, but instead of turning this topic into a philosophical discussion. Could you please point me towards the solution of this problem or guide me to where I've done wrong with regards to the code.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic Yes, I'm sorry. I tried to run this code with a salary of `32000`, and `getIncome()` returns `24577.760000000002`. Show us expected vs actual.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I get 0.00 when I run it from another class.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic See Tamar's answer. I created a new instance, called `clcSalary`, then `getIncome()`.

Comment: Let me guess:  You construct a new instance of the class and then execute the getter method on that, and expect the value to mysteriously jump from the first instance to the second one.

Comment: @Hot Licks, all the information relative to the given problem is present. No need to guess..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a driver like (which is what you have in your 3rd `else-if`)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    savings s = new savings();
    s.setSavings();
    double value = s.getSavings();
}
```

In this case, of course it's going to be 0.0 with the line

```
double income = myincome.getIncome();
```

in `setSavings()`, you haven't called the methods that change the value of `myIncome`.

In your `savings` class,

```
private income myincome = new income();
```

creates a new `income` instance, which, because you don't have a constructor, initializes the value of the instance field `myIncome` to 0. That is the value you are getting back with `getIncome()`.

You aren't calling `clcSalary()` anywhere. You should do that before calling `getIncome()`.

Comment: I see now where you are coming with that. In the way I thought - when code in Class Income would be executed, if then after I would go to Class Savings and execute setSavings - I would be able to get the variable myIncome as it would be already initialized. But as you and @HotLicks have pointed out - it creates a new instance of the class therefor returns class to initial state.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic A method doesn't get executed until you call it. A constructor will set some default values for the instance fields it doesnt' explicitly initialize. 0 for primitive types, and null for reference types.

Comment: would you be so kind and tell me if there would be a way how to go about this problem without calling clcSalary method?

Comment: @E.Doroskevic You really should separate parts of code into separate modules like methods, it's better for readability and maintainability. If you really don't want to do it from the method, you can add a constructor for your `income` class and do all that logic in the constructor.

Comment: I understand that. Thank you very much for your and everyone else's time. I know how to fix this problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Are the summery functions being printed? What is the value of myIncome there?

In other words, if `getIncome` is being called before either `clcSalary` or `clcHourlyRate` then your variable will remain 0.

Comment: This is the only thing I can see happening.

Comment: Are you calling clcSalary or clcHourlyRate before getIncome? Because if those functions are not being called, the value of myIncome will never change from the initial 0.

Comment: It would be nice to add an explanation to a minus one.

Comment: I'll make up for it till then.

Comment: Positive, I do call one of the functions before I call .getIncome(); However, it still returns 0.00 value.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic Then show us how you execute it too.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic so u get the println that requests the salary, then you enter a number and then nothing else is printed? Looking at your code I didn't see a path that didn't have a summery function call. I would start with just printing the income after reading it with the scanner to see that you get the value entered.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've edited my post. Now main class and class which uses getIncome method from class income are present as well.